# Is there any way of getting strings independent to others?

Tags: c, string

This is a process of my code.

- get string by `scanf`
- store the string in an array `arr`
- repeat this work

Here's my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    char * arr[10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        scanf("%s", str);
        arr[i] = str;
        printf("%s %p\n", arr[i], str);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```sh
aaa
aaa 0x7ffee773892e
bbb
bbb 0x7ffee773892e
ccc
ccc 0x7ffee773892e
ccc
ccc
ccc
```

Since `str` points same memory address, `arr` contains `ccc` only.
But that's not what I want, so I tried another one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * str;  /* This line is changed. */
    char * arr[10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        scanf("%s", str);
        arr[i] = str;
        printf("%s %p\n", arr[i], str);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I changed `char str[10]` → `char * str` to avoid storing same strings. Obviously `str` points different address for each loop but it still doesn't work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * str;
    char * arr[10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            str = "Hello";
        else if (i == 1)
            str = "World";
        arr[i] = str;
        printf("%s %p\n", arr[i], str);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Hello 0x1074bbfa0
World 0x1074bbfa6
World 0x1074bbfa6
Hello
World
World
```

However, it works.

I don't know what's different between second and third.
Is there any way of getting strings independent to others?

+) fgets, gets were bad too.

Comment: `char * str; ...  scanf("%s", str);` as undefined behavior because *str* is not initialized and *scanf* writes on a undefined address. You need to deep copy the strings, not to save al time the address of the same string (even its content is modified) for instance use *strdup*

Comment: Make copies of the string with `strdup`. Or allocate dynamic memory with `malloc` and read directly into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment

```
arr[i] = str;
```

This doesn't create a new copy of `str`, instead it makes `arr[i]` simply point to where `str` is pointing (which is the first element of the `str` array, or `&str[0]`). And if you do that for all elements of `arr`, then all elements will be pointing to the very same location.

If you "draw" it, it would look something like this:

```
+--------+
| arr[0] | --\
+--------+    \     +-----+
| arr[1] | ----+--> | str |
+--------+    /     +-----+
| arr[2] | --/
+--------+
| arr[3] | --> ???
+--------+
| ...... |
+--------+
```

<sub>[`arr[3]` and onward are *uninitialized*, they point to *indeterminate* locations]</sub>

One possible (and simple) solution is to make `arr` not an array of pointer, but an array of arrays:

```
char arr[10][10];
```

Now each elements of `arr` is an independent array that you can use in `scanf`

```
scanf("%9s", arr[i]);
```

<sub>[Note the length-limit added in the format, so to not write out of bounds of the array]</sub>

---

The second attempt is even worse, since then you use the *uninitialized* pointer `str` as the destination for `scanf`. That means `scanf` will write the string it reads to an *indeterminate* memory location. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

And it still have *the exact same problem* as the first program, where each of the initialized pointers in `arr` are all pointing to the very same location!

---

When you use string literals instead of an array for `str`, then you have to remember that in C all string literals are really independent arrays of characters.

That means `"Hello"` is an array of six characters (including null-terminator), and `"World"` is *another* array, totally independent from any other array.

That means `arr[0]` will point to the first character of the array for `"Hello"`, and `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` will both point to the first character of the array for `"World"`.

Both `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` will point to the same location because you don't modify `str` between the second and third iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In C assignment only copies the reference but not the string
you need **to copy** the strings and allocate memory for them.

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    char *arr[10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        scanf("%s", str);
        arr[i] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        strcpy(arr[i], str);
        printf("%s %p\n", arr[i], str);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    char arr[10][10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        scanf("%s", str);
        strcpy(arr[i], str);
        printf("%s %p\n", arr[i], str);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```